# error while opening eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

When I try opening `eclipse` it opens, but it shows one error i.e `Android SDK content Loader has encountered a problem.parseSdkContent failed`

When I click on details button, it shows me `parseSdkContent failed java.lang.NullPointeException`.

And when I tried to create AVD it shows error that `Location of the android SDK has not been setup in the preferences` while I have already set the path in preferences.

Please help me. Because of this issue my work is pending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I work in this problem for 2 days. In my workspace I have 2 projects. After review both project.properties, project 1 reference project 2 and project 2 reference project 1. This cause a stackoverflow. I comment one line and the problem is solved.

Comment: In my case, the hardware-qemu.ini file in the C:\users\user_name\emulator_name.avd has references to another .avd path. Once I removed them, the error vanished. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This annoying error popped up every time I started Eclipse and even a reinstall didn't work.

Look at the .log file in the .metadata of your workspace to find more about this error.
Mine said:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectDescription.hasPublicChanges(ProjectDescription.java:509)

Eventually I found out that a .project file was missing a < name > tag that got lost somewhere when I renamed the project on the SVN server. So make sure the file isn't corrupt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><projectDescription>
<name>ProjectName</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your android-sdk-windows in the same directory where your eclipse folder is and the name shout be - android-sdk-windows .

Comment: i did the same but still same problem is there. what to do?

Comment: That kinda worked after half hour struggle. Man i'm tired of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I closed all the projects then you can set the Android SDK Location. Thereafter need to open one by one and fix

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and killed my two hours to resolve the issues. I have checked my work space and got two projects where `project.properties` file `#project target= android-10` as the similar target with one of my another project to integrate `Facebook SDK`. I have completely deleted one project and reinstalled `Eclipse-Indio 4.2.1` and then resolve the problem. Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the avd file in your .android  folder and restart the eclipse..
it should be mostly in c:/users/... search for avd in windows search. worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Android throws these usual BS problems "Android Content SDK Loader..." and "R cannot be resolved ..." often when there are simple coding errors in String XML or Manifest.

I just happen to have my XML in string name="city-state-zip" while there should'nt be any special characters in the name. But I only found it when Android finally pointed me to this error through gen/package/R.java file

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to recently added library...
In my case i had added two libraries andengine and box2d..
delete them and restart the eclipse and reinstall the libraries ...

Answer (score -1):

Delete the avd file in your `.android` and then try to configure your new avd. It worked awesomely.

Comment: I think you need to give our more details. If you have got this information from some reliable source, you should also share a link.