# Unknown exception in parseSdkContent

Tags: android, adt

I haven't found an answer or similar situation to this on the internet so I'm asking on here.
When I start eclipse I'm bombarded with a number of dialogs. The first being an `Unknown exception in parseSdkContent` with the message `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Subsequently as a result another dialog `Android SDK Content Loader has encountered a problem` with the message `parseSdkContent failed`. Nearly all projects have errors being `the import android cannot be resolved`. When clicking on AVD/SDK manager via the eclipse menu I get a dialog saying `'Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences'`. So I checked the SDK location and it is perfectly fine pointing towards the sdk folder containing sdk/avd manager etc.. I can't seem to figure this out. I've tried reinstalling the sdk with no luck.
I'd greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks

Edit: Here's what the .log file is saying

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-20 14:49:27.618
!MESSAGE parseSdkContent failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.getLibraries(ProjectState.java:328)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:660)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:663)
```

the com.android... line is repeated many times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the file is referencing another file leading to some sort of infinite loop?  Such a situation is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646889/error-while-opening-eclipse)(NPE).  Maybe you have renamed the project or moved directories which created an error?  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019051/android-sdk-content-loader-failing-with-nullpointerexception) is a similiar error but it is also created by a null pointer exception, but maybe some of the answers will be applicable.  Also, I have heard of problems with the SDK when it is loaded in directories with a space.  So if your SDK is located in "Program Files", maybe try moving it to another folder in your root directory "c:\SDK".  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this partially helped me, so I'll accept it as the right answer and comment what I did. I loaded eclipse with a different workspace and tried the avd manager from the eclipse menu and it ran fine which confirmed a problem with one or more of the projects. I deleted a few projects which were referencing each other. I then went into project.properties, and manually removed any offending references from there. I then cleaned all projects and checked all build paths.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue, but was able to quickly resolve it. I was moving File1 from projectA to projectB. When I tried to add the library reference of ProjectB to ProjectA my system crashed as above. The issue was ProjectB already had a library reference to ProjectA (Hence the infinite loop issue). I just opened my ProjectA project.properties and deleted the reference. When I restarted Eclipse everything was better.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Find the folder named: .android

This folder can be located in your Windows user directory, for example in Windows 8: C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME.android Step 2. Delete this folder .android

Step 3. Restart Eclipse and it is OK now. Its worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, two projects were referencing each other. Project A and B were both library and they were library of each other.